# write() prints in wrong order

Tags: c

I'm trying to output ordered set of lines created by multiple processes.

I found that `printf()` and `fprintf()` is not suitable for such task. Right now I'm using this set of commands:

```
sprintf(buff,"%d: some string", (*counter)++); //build string (write can't do that)
write(file, buff, strlen(buff));
memset(buff, 0, strlen(buff)); //clear buffer before next writing
```

File opening and starting processes is shown below:

```
int file;
int main(){
    pid_t busPID, riderPID;
    file = open("outputFile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    if((busPID = fork()) == 0){
        bus();
    else{
        if((riderPID = fork()) == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                rider();
            }
        }else{
            pid_t waitPID;
            while ((waitPid = wait(&status)) > 0); //wait for all riders to finish
        }
    }
    waitpid(busPID, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are functions, which prints output:

```
void bus() {
    char buff[50];
    //writing
    do {
        //writing
        if(*onStop > 0) {
            //writing
            sem_post(semRider);
            sem_wait(semBus);
            //writing
            *onStop = 0; //internal value, irrelevant for answer
        }
        //writing
        usleep(rand()%busSleep);
        //writing
        sem_post(semRider);
        sem_wait(semBus);
        departuredAkt += temp; //internal value, irrelevant for answer
    } while(departuredAkt < departuredTotal);
    //writing
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); //exit this process
}

void rider() {
    char buff[50];
    //writing
    int pos = ++(*onStop);
    //writing
    sem_wait(semRider);
    //writing
    sem_post(semBus);
    sem_wait(semRider);
    //writing
    sem_post(semBus);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

There is only 1 process using `bus()` function and N processes using `rider()`function (specified by argument). desired output is:

```
1: bus string
2: bus string
3: bus string
4: rider 1 string
5: rider 1 string
.
.
.
25: rider N string
26: bus string
```

My current output looks like this:

```
1: bus string
2: bus string
3: bus string
4: rider 1 string
6: bus string //here is the problem
5: rider 1 string
```

Question is, how can I achieve printing lines in correct order?

Comment: You'll need to store your results in some kind of datastructure, and then print them out once all threads have finished.

Comment: Or make every write do an open-in-append-mode/write/close.

Comment: 1) Neither your `bus()` nor `rider()` functions, as posted, do any printing (the comments presumably show where, but not what). 2) Why do you call `fprintf()` unsuitable? Is it because you have a file descriptor and not a `FILE *`? See [mcve].

Comment: Why do you clear the buffer? You're only using the bytes written by the `sprintf` call. Also, `sprintf` returns the number of characters it printed, making the `strlen` call unnecessary.

Comment: If you called either `printf()` or `fprintf()`, followed by `fflush()`, you would probably get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: the `fork()` function has 3 possible return states <0 means an error occurred.  ==0 means the child process is running.  >0 means the parent process is running.   The posted code fails to take those three conditions into account

Comment: the output streams are all buffered in the OS.  the way to get immediate output of the data is to append a '\n' to each of the format strings in the calls to `printf()` and `fprintf()`

Comment: regarding: `while ((waitPid = wait(&status)) > 0);`  the variable: `status` is not defined within the posted code!  Please correct that oversight

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing the calls to `sem_open()` and `sem_unlink()` and fails to check the returned/status values from the several calls to the sem_...() functions

Comment: regarding" `sprintf(buff,"%d: some string", (*counter)++);  change the format string from" `%d: some string`  to `%d: some string\n` so the data is immediately written to the terminal rather than waiting until either the output buffer overflows or the program ends

Answer (score 1):

First of all, side note: never use `sprintf`, this function is completely unsecure. Use `snprintf`. Example:

```
snprintf (buff, sizeof (buff), "%d: some string", (*counter)++);
```

Second: you missed information we need to understand your question. I mean the following information:

- How exactly you opened file?
- How you started you processes?
- Are this processes really processes or they are threads?
- Did you open file in one process and somehow shared this opened file with other processes or did you opened the file in each process separately?

This details are critical for understanding your question.

Next time you will writing some question, please, provide FULL EXAMPLE. I. e. minimal working example we can compile and run. It should include all relevant details, i. e. starting processes, opening files, etc. And, of course, you should strip all unnecessary details.

Okey, there is two different notion in POSIX: "file descripTOR" and "file descripTION". Websearch for them. Type "man 2 open" in UNIX shell and read carefully, this manual page talks about distinction.

Exact details about how you started your processes and how you opened your file causes (or not causes) sharing of file description between processes and thus affects behavior of "write".

I wrote big text about file descriptors and descriptions. I put it here: https://zerobin.net/?eb2d99ee02f36b92#hQY7vTMCD9ekThAod+bmjlJgnlBxyDSXCYcgmjVSu2w= , because it is not much relevant to this question, but still will be useful for education.

Okey, what to do?

Well, if you for whatever reason cannot share ONE file DESCRIPTION, then simply open file with O_APPEND. :) You don't need to open the file every time you write to it. Simply open it with O_APPEND one time in each process and all will be OK.

Comment: If you're going to use `snprintf`, you should check its return value. `sprintf` *can* be used safely with some care; for example, `sprintf(buff, "%d: some string", n)` is safe if `buff` is big enough to hold the string plus the widest possible `int` value. If you don't check the return value of `snprintf`, it will silently truncate the string, which can be just as bad as an overflow; consider truncating `rm -rf /tmp/tmpdir` to `rm -rf /`.

Comment: Processes are started by `fork()` in `main()`. File is opened by this command: `file = open("proj2.out", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_TRUNC, 0666);` and is opened in `main()` before forking so every process can access it. `file`  is gobal variable. I will add this info to question.